# trigger 2 different actions depending on duration between 2 ‘onTap’

Tags: swift, swiftui, duration

For a button, each time it is tapped, how to trigger a code1 (set a specific var to value1) when ‘onTap’ occured less than 60 seconds ago or  code2 (set a specific variable to value2) when onTap occured more than 60 seconds ago ?

==> Working solution implemented for duration = 10 seconds

```
Button(action: {
            self.date = Date()
            let hour = self.calendar.component(.hour, from: self.date)
            let minutes = self.calendar.component(.minute, from: self.date)
            let seconds = self.calendar.component(.second, from: self.date)
            self.newdate = hour*3600+minutes*60+seconds
    
            if (self.lastdate == 0){
                print(" First Tap...")
            }else
            if (self.newdate-self.lastdate) < 10  {
                    print("Tap before 10 sec =>  call Func1")
                    
                } else {
                print("Tap > 10 seconds => call Func2")
                           }
            self.lastdate = hour*3600+minutes*60+seconds
           
                         }) {
            Text("One")
                            }
```

Comment: Would you show your code how did you try?

Comment: Button(action: {
     
            if (self.value3 == "One tapped after x seconds")
                {
                    print(self.value3)
                } else {
                self.value3 = "One tapped before x seconds"
                print(self.value3)
                           }
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10.0) {
                              print("more than x seconds elapsed since last 'tap'")
                self.value3 = "One tapped after x seconds"
                                                          }

Comment: Move your code from the comment into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete example that works for an interval of 5 seconds (to make testing quicker).

It uses `@State` vars to update the `Date` of the `lastTap` and `message` and uses `.timeIntervalSince(last)` to measure the time in seconds.  The first tap is detected when `lastTap` is still `nil`.

Changing the `message` causes the view to redraw and update the message on the screen.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var lastTap: Date? = nil
    @State private var message = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
            Text(message)
            Button("Tap me") {
                let now = Date()
                if let last = self.lastTap {
                    if now.timeIntervalSince(last) > 5 {
                        self.message = "Greater than 5 seconds"
                    } else {
                        self.message = "Less than 5 seconds"
                    }
                } else {
                    self.message = "First tap"
                }
                self.lastTap = now
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var lastTapTimestamp: Date?

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        defer { lastTapTimestamp = Date() }
        guard let date = lastTapTimestamp else {
            callFunc1()
            return
        }
        if Int(Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate) - Int(date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate) >= 3600 {
            callFunc2()
        } else {
            callFunc1()
        }
    }
```